# Camel Azure credentials as option instead of bean

Tags: azure, apache-camel

I want to pass credentials, to Azure blob component, without having to create and register a bean.

I have a route which consumes a file and routes it to an Azure Blob

I want this route to be generic.

The challenge I am facing is.

1. I have to support multiple storage accounts
2. We are supposed to fetch the credentials from a key vault. The credentials can change any time and I don't have control. The blob component requires a bean for credentials. So the only option I am left is a bean. So while I was able to achieve this, wondering, if camel should be able to receive the credentials, not the object or client , but the account name and key as  an option. Camel doesn't support key vault which is kind of a bummer.I might be able to help with implementing the keyVault solution

Answer (score 1):

This is the bean I wrote to achieve what I wanted.

from(file://somedir).to(bean:azureService?sendFiletoAzure(name,key,container);

AzureService{

```
    public void sendFileToAzure(String storageAccountName,
            String storageAccountKey, String containerName, Exchange exchange) {
        StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(
                storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);
        SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
        GenericFile<?> file = (GenericFile<?>) exchange.getIn().getBody();
        String blobName = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("blobName");
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
        registry.put("blobCredentials", credentials);
        String endpointUri = String.format(azureEndpointUri, storageAccountName,
                containerName, blobName);
        context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody(endpointUri, file);
    }
 }
```